# How to run special characters in field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

How to run a special character in field calculator in arcmap. Special character is not working in arcmap field calculator.

i need Like this (Três into Tres)

---

I am using this code in python

```
!ADDRESS_N!.replace("Três","Tres")
```

Comment: Are you asking how to change Três into Tres? What is the code you are trying with in Field Calculator? Could you add a screenshot showing the attribute table?

Comment: "I am using this code in python" !ADDRESS_N!.replace("Três","Tres")

Comment: Do you get an error or just no change?

Comment: Thank you. Its working fine.